# Understanding a Gemara in Pesachim

Tags: talmud-gemara, rashi, kohen-priest, maseches-pesachim

In the Gemara, Mascheta Pesachim it brings a case on [daf 9b](https://www.sefaria.org/Pesachim.9a.11?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) which I am rather puzzled, baffled with regards to what the case is. The [Rashi](https://www.sefaria.org/Pesachim.9b.1?lang=bi&p2=Rashi_on_Pesachim.9b.1.2&lang2=bi) which is at the top of Daf 9b I also find puzzling. Who is the Kohan related to?
Please can I have some explanation on this Gemara.  In the words of Rashi how do we explain the Kohen being in relation to whoever he is related to, as I do know to who he is related to?

Comment: Please be more specific, what is your question exactly?

Comment: Also, it's 9b, not a

Comment: Need clarification of the case which is brought down in the braysa I quoted.

Comment: @TheGRAPKE it's starts at the bottom of 9a

Comment: I stand corrected. So a cohen was sent to look into the pit to advise the mother how many days of tumah and taharah to keep, what's the problem?

Comment: @TheGRAPKE ik that's the case. All I'm uncertain about is the Rashi Sub Verbo Leida

Comment: The cohen was simply the dude who was sent to check. I think that's about it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118668/discussion-between-russell-and-the-grapke).

Answer (score 0):

The story is brought to bring out the concept of 'ein sofek motzi midei vadai' - i.e. that an uncertainty/doubt (sofek) is not enough to remove something from being a definitive/certain.

Therefore, the Gemara brings the case of a maidservant belonging to an owner who was deemed a 'metzik' (an oppressor) who flung a stillborn into an open pit. A kohen later came past and looked into the pit to work out whether the stillborn was a male or female. This was to ascertain how long the tumah (the impure) period followed by a period of tahara (pure) would be which is dependent on the gender of the child. After this time she can then be with her husband again. If it is a boy she would be tamei for one week and then have a 33 day pure period, but with a girl she would be impure for 14 days followed by a further 66 days.

The problem now is that we have a kohen and we have a dead body which is strong source of tumah. By leaning over the pit the Kohen has exposed himself to this tumah.

The Gemara tell us that in the chachomim ruled that the Kohen was tahor as weasels and 'bardelas' were common there and likely would have dragged away the body of the stillborn ensuring that he would no longer be exposed to a tamei source.

This sets up the question whereby returning to the premise of 'ein sofek motzi midei vadai' - you have a 'vadai', a definitive, that there is a shifchah who threw the stillborn in the pit. But we have a 'sofeik', a doubt whether or not the body was taken by these animals. And yet we see, in that case that the sages ruled the Kohen to be pure which means they were happy to rule on the premise that there may have been an animal (i.e. a sofeik) that removed the body.

Comment: But surely why would a Kohen be Metamei by the miscarried child surely he wasn't alive to being with

Comment: Rashi says that the Kohen was a 'karov' - a relative or 'mibnei bayis' from the same household and that is why he went to help

Comment: Ye but  if he was a member of the same household is he not perfectly fine going within the pit?

Comment: @Russell See Tos. 9a (s.v. "בשפחתו") who cites the Ri that that kohein acted wrongly to risk contamination because 1. it's not permitted to become *tamei* for a *neifel* regardless of familial relation, and 2. the motive for this kohen's decision to lean over and potentially become *tamei* wasn't *l'tzorech hameis* ("ואומר ר"י דכהן שוטה היה דאפילו אם נאמר של גבירתה היה וכהן זה קרוב היה לא היה לו ליטמא דאמרינן בתורת כהנים דאין כהן מטמא לנפלים דדומיא דאביו ואמו בעינן בני קיימא ועוד דכאן לא היה לצורך המת"). No reason to assume Rashi disagrees, though he only briefly mentions "ולא נזהר אותו כהן".

Comment: @Fred  I'm rather puzzled since a Neifel is not a viable person like the Kohein's Mother and Father

Comment: @Russell You may have mistakenly parsed Tosafos when you were reading it. " דאין כהן מטמא לנפלים דדומיא דאביו ואמו בעינן בני קיימא" means "A kohein may not contaminate himself for a neifel, for we require that a corpse have had a presumption of survival while alive - like one's father or mother - in order to allow a kohein to contaminate himself for them." Let's say, for example, that the neifel in this case was the kohein's brother. The kohein assumed that he was a karov and can risk contamination, but the kohein was wrong in his reasoning.

Comment: @Fred Still unsure though since doesn't say he assumed to be a karov, Rashi says that the Kohein was a Karov?

Comment: @Russell I think it's safe to assume that Rashi didn't literally mean that the kohein was halachically a karov sufficient to be m'tamei for the neifel (since that's impossible for any neifel), especially since Rashi uses the non-specific language of "וכהן קרוב או מבני הבית היה". The kohein wasn't knowledgeable, but he was aware that there was some kind of halacha about relatives being allowed to contaminate themselves, so the kohein just assumed he was a sufficient karov.